# MissingOptionsException: The required option "class" is missing

Tags: symfony

I am getting the above error when trying to use a entity field type in a form.

I am using Symfony 2.6.0.

My class has a category field defined as:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="parent")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;
```

The category class is defined as:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Parent", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $parents;
```

My form type has definition for the category as:

```
->add('category', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Category',
                'property' => 'name'
```

In my controller I am calling it with:

```
->add('category', 'entity')
```

The stack trace is below:

```
Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\MissingOptionsException: The required option "class" is missing.
at n/a
    in \project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver.php line 757

at Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver->resolve(array())
    in \project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormType.php line 109

at Symfony\Component\Form\ResolvedFormType->createBuilder(object(FormFactory), 'category', array())
    in \project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\DataCollector\Proxy\ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy.php line 82

at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\DataCollector\Proxy\ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy->createBuilder(object(FormFactory), 'category', array())
    in \project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory.php line 87

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory->createNamedBuilder('category', 'entity', null, array())
    in \project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder.php line 106

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->create('category', 'entity', array())
    in \project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder.php line 268

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->resolveChildren()
    in \project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder.php line 216

at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->getForm()
    in \project\src\AppBundle\Controller\TheController.php line 78

at AppBundle\Controller\TheController->editAction('30', object(Request))
    in  line 

at call_user_func_array(array(object(TheController), 'editAction'), array('30', object(Request)))
    in \project\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 3008

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
    in \project\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2970

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in \project\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 3119

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in \project\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2364

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
    in \project\web\app_dev.php line 28
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have created a form class, but are recreating the form in the controller rather than using the form class.

> In my controller I am calling it with:
>   `->add('category', 'entity')`

You should either use the same `class` and `property` options as you did in the form class, or better, use the form class in the controller instead of recreating the form.

`$this->createForm(new ParentType(), $parent);`

Comment: I am using the following construct: `$form = $this->createFormBuilder($actor)->add('category', 'entity')->getForm();` this works in another form. Its not working with the 'entity' field type though.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it pointed me in the right direction. I modified my code to use `$form = $this->createForm(new ParentType(), $parent, array('method' => 'GET'));` but there was a secondary issue with the FormBuilderInterface which was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359307/registrationformtypebuildform-not-compatible).